# Does Data Protection API in ASP.NET Core prevent replay attacks?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core

I'm using the Cookie Middleware in ASP.NET Core for session cookies. The session cookie data is encrypted by the framework using the Data Protection API.

Just wanted to understand in detail what the level of protection is from this process. These are my current assumptions:

- The cookie data cannot be viewed in transit or at rest in the browser and is tamper-proof
- The cookie data can be replayed if sniffed over HTTP
- The cookie data cannot be replayed if issued and sent only via HTTPS

If any of these assumptions are wrong or need more detail then I'd appreciate an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumptions are right: although authentication cookies are marked as `HttpOnly` by default, nothing prevents an attacker from stealing a cookie from browser's container and using it as-is to make malicious requests if he manages to install a malware on victim's machine.

---

In the future, ASP.NET Core will support a feature called "TLS token binding" that will make stealing authentication cookies much harder.

When supported by both the server and the user agent, this feature allows the server to bind sensitive data like authentication cookies or bearer tokens with a secret value  only known by the original client (i.e by the browser).

In ASP.NET Core, this feature will be implemented at the cryptographic level: the secret transmitted by the browser will be used to derive the encryption/validation keys used by Data Protection to protect and unprotect the authentication cookies, so that no one will be able to use a stolen cookie without also sending the corresponding token.

Comment: Note: TLS token binding is already implemented in the cookies middleware, but this feature is not supported by the official servers (i.e WebListener and Kestrel, even behind IIS). You can follow the progress here: https://github.com/aspnet/WebListener/issues/231 https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/736 https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/24

Comment: Thanks for the TLS token binding info, I'll keep an eye on that.